# Importing Excel into Word using templates. Where do I start?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I'm looking to populate word template from excel file. My excel file is going to include several rows, each with a name, and a few number entries, so something like:

```
Firstname, Lastname, 1,2,3,4
```

What I'd like to do is automatically create a different word document for each row. Each word would be the same template, only with different numbers, based on the row.

Is there any way to batch this, so that a word file with the the data in each row would be included ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with following code:

```
Sub AutoSend2Word()
Dim i, lastRow As Long
Dim objWord, objDoc As Object

lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objselection = objWord.Selection
    With objselection
       .TypeText Range("A" & i).Value & Chr(10)
       .TypeText Range("B" & i).Value & Chr(10)
       .TypeText Range("C" & i).Value & Chr(10)
       .TypeText Range("D" & i).Value & Chr(10)
       .TypeText Range("E" & i).Value & Chr(10)
       .TypeText Range("F" & i).Value & Chr(10)
       .TypeText Range("G" & i).Value & Chr(10)
    End With
    Filename = "D:\MyFirstSave_" & Format(Now, "hh mm ss")
    objDoc.SaveAs Filename
    Set objselection = Nothing
Next i

Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```